# FFmpeg and FIR filtering

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to use the FIR filter function from the FFmpeg library. I would like to find similar functions that are implemented for IIR filter:

```
ff_iir_filter_init_coeffs(),ff_iir_filter()
```

So I need simple functions like `fir_init_coef()` and `fir_filter()` – prepare coefficients and .use them for filtering. Nothing more.

Coefficients itself will be calculated outside.

I already use the resampling part of the FFmpeg library. There was a good example for this functionality. But not for FIR.

What functions from FFmpeg lib can you recommend for this?

Comment: Can you make use of functions in (https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavfilter/af_afir.c)?

Comment: You can't use those functions directly as they are not declared in a publicly installed header of the library. Just look at them and define them in your code.